# How to create a cell array of empty character vectors of a certain size

Tags: matlab

Is there a way create an N-by-1 cell array of empty characters?

For example, `cellstr(repmat('a',2,1))` produces `{'a';'a'}`.

But `cellstr(repmat('',2,1))` or `cellstr(char.empty(32,0))` produces what seems to be `cell(1)`. For example, `containers.Map({'1','2'},cellstr(repmat('',2,1))` would give a number of keys and values mismatch error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `repmat` on a cell of empty string. For example:

```
repmat({''},2,1);
```

Comment: @Argyll, please do not add some content on an answer without asking.